# Play Song in AVAudio Player after a certain time iOS Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am working on app in which I select music from library and play with AVAudio Player. But I want to play this song after 10 Seconds. But I am unable how to do this. Here is my code.

```
func checkTime(){
 counter = 10        
    if (audioPlayer.currentTime <= 10) {
        timerLabel.text = String(counter)
        counter -= 1
        timer.invalidate()
        audioPlayer.play()   
    }
}
```

I see many links but did not match my scenario. I call this function in timer. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your counter with `Timer.scheduledTimer` to create 10 seconds counter and you can play your audio when `counter` reaches 0. Like this way:

```
var counter = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateCounter() {
    if counter > 0 {
        counter -= 1
    } else if counter == 0 {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```